# How to solve "The page failed to provide a valid list of administrators." error when creating a like via own website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Im having a lot of difficulties in getting my like button to work on my website. When I click the like button i get to following message:

***The page failed to provide a valid list of administrators. It needs to specify the administrators using either a "fb:app_id" meta tag, or using a "fb:admins" meta tag to specify a comma-delimited list of Facebook users.***

For my page: http://tutorio.nl/fb/bmw.html I have the following code setup.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<title>BMW Auto</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="Dikke BMW X6"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="product"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.tutorio.nl/fb/bmw.html"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.tutorio.nl/fb/bmw-x6.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="tutorio.nl"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100000369901095"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="160395427395748"/>
<meta property="og:description"
      content="De BMW X6 crossover een geliefde auto voor vele."/>  
</head>
<body><p><img src="bmw-x6.jpg" title="Mercedes E-Klasse Coupe"/></p>
    <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Ftutorio.nl%2Ffb%2Fbmw.html&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;
    width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35&amp;appId=160395427395748"
    scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</body>
```

I've gone over the docs so many can't see where i'm going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this great tool that facebook provides us :
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
It will allow you to debug your `og:tags` - and tell you whats missing and what values are not accepted.  From a quick glance it seems there is a conflict between the `og_products:product` and `fb:app_id` parameters.  Check out the link, feed your URL into the tool and it should assist you in solving this issue.
In addition the [Open Graph Protocol Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) on facebook should shed some light with regard to what the parameters mean and what values are accepted.

Comment: thanks for the tool. Still dealing with the issue. I read about the javascript SDK that can be included in the code. I do not have this included. Can that be the reason why this like button isn't working?

Comment: you have still not resolved the issues that the debug tool is finding... Solve those errors first before trying another solution.  The javascript SDK is a very important tool aswell - but it has no relation to the like button (with regard to `og:tags`).