# Fix "Failed to provide a valid list of administrators" on Like buttons

Tags: facebook-like, admin

I get an error "Failed to provide a valid list of administrators" on *some* (hail, non-determinism!) of my Like buttons on two different websites. Both have a valid `fb:app_id` meta tag and show no error in the Open Graph object debugger.

One of my non-likable objects: http://twizy2night.com/very-bad-cannes-mission-impossible.php

I'm aware of the [amount](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14296/how-do-i-resolve-no-administrators-were-specified-error-with-the-facebook-like) of [questions](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7491111/facebook-like-wont-keep-track-of-likes-after-browser-refresh) concerning this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513334/how-to-solve-the-page-failed-to-provide-a-valid-list-of-administrators-error), but none of the answers fix *my* problem.

It sounds like a bug on Facebook side (or a cache thing), but I could be missing something, and I can't find a reported issue on Facebook Bug Tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try also adding the `fb:admins` tag to your pages:

`<meta property="fb:admins" content="xxx,yyy,zzz" />`

Comment: The [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/) only uses `fb:app_id`. But I'm going to try anyway and see what happens.

Comment: It worked. I'll update my bug report according to this new information.